# Closing class IO resources in overridden finalize() method

Tags: java, garbage-collection

If I have a class that utilizes an IO resource, such as a disk flat file, DB, or some other form of external resource, what are pros and cons of closing those streams/connections in an overridden finalize() method to be run by GC?  I though this could leverage the existing JVM GC and reduce the exposure to the risk of relying on the client to invoke a class method called something like closeResources() as well as writing spaghetti-like try-catches (nested try-catches and ifs being my least favorite programming constructs).

As a concrete example, I have a simple file reading wrapper.  The class is constructed with `String filePath`, it reads the file into a `List<String[]>` .  I don't wan't to have to close the `BufferedReader` in multiple places like close it if there is a problem opening the file (catch clause) but also close it if the file reads fine etc.  I want to put it in one place and make sure it is ALWAYS closed no matter what when the object gets GC.

Is this approach a good practice or am I trying to afford myself too high level a convenience within the scope of Java?

Comment: Is the `BufferedReader` variable local to the constructor, to other method, or is it an instance variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a great idea as the `finalize()` method is not guaranteed to be called.

It's easier and better to just close the resources when your code is done with them.

If you hate writing the nested try-finally blocks to close the resources correctly, use something like [commons-io's](http://commons.apache.org/io/) [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly%28java.io.InputStream%29) to silently close the resources (or write your own simple util method to silently close them):

```
InputStream stream = ...;
try {
    ...
}
finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(stream);
}
```

Comment: imo, i'd use google guava, as it has a lot of functionality, instead of including all the apache libraries. with google guava, you can use the `Files` class

Answer (score 2):

**When the IO resource is an instance variable**, then you should close it in the `finalize()` method.

Why ?

1. Because beeing an instance variable, you need it in an open state because some method will be using it repeated times.
2. If you close it in a method other than finalize, then you are creating a `temporal coupling`, meaning the class user needs to know that he has to call certain methods in a certain temporal order, i.e, A before B etc.

EDIT:

Java documentation states that garbage collector is not guaranteed to run at any **specific time**, and will not run  `finalize()` as long as there's any **references** to the object. If references linger, it's a memory leak, a programming error. `finalize()` is the best option when the resource is not local to a method. If the resource is local to a method, then  close it in the `finally` end of a `try/cath block`.

Comment: thanks for elaborating.  what's conflicting with @matt b is that you assume that finalize() is guaranteed to be executed.  i am curious to find out more on that.

Comment: basically, what it boils down to is whether finalize() is guaranteed or not and generally how reliable it is

Comment: @foampile Java documentation states that garbage collector is not guaranteed to run at any **specific time**, and will not run  `finalize()` as long as there's any **references** to the object. If references linger, it's a memory leak, a programming error. `finalize()` is the best option when the resource is not local to a method. If the resource is local to a method, then  close it in the `finally` end of a `try/cath block`.

Comment: @foampile `try/catch/finally` blocks are not spagetti code. **Au contraire** . It's well structured code. Error code checking and tag-jumpig is spagetti code. `try/catch/finally` (Exception handling) was created to avoid spagetti code.

Comment: i didn't say they all are.  but when you have a try/catch/finally and then in the finally then you have another try { close } catch {do nothing}, that is more mundane code than i like to have in my classes

Comment: @foampile Point in favor of `finalize()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, finally block is always the best approach to release the resources such as connection, I/O Sreams etc.

Comment: i am talking about overriding Object.finalize(), not the final block of a try/catch